# Unable to use npm modules in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm coming from Babel to Typescript and I'm struggling to import a module from `node_modules`. The resulting `.js` build does not include the code the from the module I'm importing ... in this case [browser-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-cookies).

I installed the package using yarn: `yarn add browser-cookies`. I then attempt to import into `main.ts` like so:

```
const cookies = require('browser-cookies');

(function() {
  document.forms['number-generator'].addEventListener('submit', (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();

    if(!cookies.get('ab')) {
      cookies.set('ab', 'true', { expires: 1 });
    }
  })
})();
```

My `package.json` file is below:

```
{
  "name": "lucky-lotto-lander",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc src/app.ts --outFile dist/app.js --module amd --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.53",
    "browser-cookies": "^1.1.0",
    "copyfiles": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

The resulting `main.js` build looks like this:

```
var cookies = require('browser-cookies');
(function () {
    document.forms['number-generator'].addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        if (!cookies.get('ab')) {
            cookies.set('ab', 'true', { expires: 1 });
        }
    });
})();
```

How can I get the necessary `browser-cookies` code to be bundled into the build?

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript alone doesn't do bundling (compare it to Babel, which also only transpiles, not bundles).

You'll need a module bundler like Webpack to make it all into one bundle.

Comment: That makes sense. For some reason I assumed it bundles too. I'll use webpack as I do with Babel. Thanks.